# Can you cache a string (eg. MySql request) with opcache?

Tags: php, opcache

I do realise that opcache is made to cache php script functionality, but is there a trick to cache whole sql request(as a string maybe)? It's important because i have limited amount of sql requests and i cannot install anything on this web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a **user cache** not an **opcode cache**. Commonly used caches include but are not limited to [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/). Additionally, there are many [cache libraries available on packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=cache).

Comment: I suppose that's the only option then. I am using a cheap wwww-hosting so i can't install a Memcached or any other user cache. I will have to pay a little bit more then. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Cheap VMs are the same price as hosting these days. I get a server in Australia for only $5 US per month. With a VM you have complete freedom on extensions, versions and software you use.